# How to change the values from a loop in Selenium automatically

Tags: selenium

example:
Scripts is to create account. (username and password)
In the loop I just have to add new username (like user1, user2 ...) with same passwords.
how to execute this loop automatically passing new values every time ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the case of data-driven test. If you are using TestNG then you can define data provider. Also [formerly ISFW now QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) has some ready to use features for data-driven testing.